# Knowing the orientation of UIImage taken from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an iPad app that allows the user to take a photo using the `UIImagePickerController`. The image is stored in an array called **photos** and a thumbnail is placed in a `UITableView` as shown.

[image]

When the user taps on the thumbnail the full picture is displayed in `UIImage` called **photoImageView** using the following code. The problem I have is knowing whether the picture has been taken in landscape (thumbnails 1 and 3) or portrait (thumbnail 2) so that I can display the `UIImage` in the correct rotation.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
photoImageView.image=[photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
photoImageView.frame=CGRectMake(190, 134, 700, 448);
}
```

It may be that I need to store the orientation in the array too - is that possible?

Also is there a way of centring the thumbnails in the `UITableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the `size` property of the `UIImage` object and compare the `width` and `height`. 
It may be some other way to do it as well, but that's how I do it.

For centering the images in `UITableView` (assuming that you're refering to the `imageView` property of the `UITableViewCell`), set the `contentMode` property of the `UIView` to whatever you want (`UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` usually does this).

Comment: Excellent thanks. I can't seem to get the image centred though. cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; does not move the portrait thumbnail to the centre. Have I done that correctly?

Comment: Glad I could help you, thank you for upvoting and accepting the answer as well. hmmm not sure about your next issue, but this is supposed to work. Maybe subclass `UITableViewCell` and add your own `UIImageView`, or load it from a nib file (this also counts as subclassing).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **imageOrientation** property of the **UIImage**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.photo = (UIImage*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

     //self.photo.imageOrientation is the orientation
}
```